# One to One field causing integrity error on insert via admin

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I am trying to use the django admin interface to insert both a venue and an address (that are mapped 1:1) in a single form.

In my model:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Address(models.Model):
    states = {
        ...
    }
    countries = {
        ...
    }
    venue = models.OneToOneField('clubApp.Venue')
    address_line1 = models.CharField("Address line 1", max_length=50)
    address_line2 = models.CharField("Address line 2", max_length=50, blank=True)
    suburb = models.CharField("Suburb", max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=states)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=countries)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s, %s, %s, %s" % (self.address_line1, self.address_line2, self.suburb, self.state, self.country)
```

and in my admin.py:

```
class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address


class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AddressInline
    ]

admin.site.register(Venue, VenueAdmin)
```

When I insert I get an Integrity Error, that 'null value in column "address_id" violates not-null constraint' which I assume is due to inserting the venue before the address into the database (postgres). What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: Where is this field `address_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Why is the relationship set in the address and not in the venue?

Unless it's a requirement on purpose, you can simply make the address not mandatory (blank=True, null=True); also I prefer more explicit code:

```
In address:

venue = models.OneToOneField(
    to=Address,
    to_field='id',
    related_name='address',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

It makes more sense to set it in the Venue to me (you don't need to declare it in both models):

```
address = models.OneToOneField(
    to=Venue,
    to_field='id',
    related_name='venue',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I originally had address set in venue, but then I would get a 'Address has no foreign key to Venue' type error due to the inlines in the modeladmin. I don't want to allow address to be null as I want to ensure that all venues have an address. 

Looking around the web, it seems that what I want to do can't be done. I have given up on inlining, it is not a major deal, just would have been nice.

Comment: It's possible but you'll need to test it as it's not built-in Django: https://gist.github.com/ramusus/4343464. In a similar situation I used a formset though (not in the admin...).

Comment: Thanks for the link, that looks promising

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
venue = models.OneToOneField('clubApp.Venue')
```

To this:

```
venue = models.OneToOneField(Venue)
```